# "There is not enough memory or disk space to complete the operation" error when opening Outlook

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook-2016

Opening Outlook 2016 on Windows 10 shows the following error:

[image]

There is more than enough RAM and disk space available, so the error message is not particularly helpful. How can the error be fixed?

Comment: The best advice I have to solve this problem, would be to to uninstall Office 2016, then to simply reinstall it.  This is either caused by a corrupt software installation or a permission problem.  The corrupt software installation is fixed by my suggestion, the corrupt permission problem, is fixed by creating a new user.

Comment: Connected and Related documentaton: ["There is not enough memory or disk space to complete the operation" error when you start an Office for Mac program](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/980616/-there-is-not-enough-memory-or-disk-space-to-complete-the-operation-error-when-you-start-an-office-for-mac-program)

Comment: Is it the `32bit` version by any chance?  I have had similar issues with users, but usually with the `32bit` version.

Comment: @CheesusCrust 64 bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was resolved after deleting a corrupt email with weird symbols:

[image]

So it seems that Outlook shows this message when it parses certain characters.

Comment: You need to mark this as the accepted answer!